# Residue of a Function Not at the Pole

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How do we calculate the residue of
$$f\left(z\right) = \frac{z\sin\left(z\right)}{\left(z-\pi\right)^{3}}$$
at $z=3$, using the equation
$$R\left(z_{0}\right) = \lim_{z\to z_{0}}\left[\frac{1}{\left(m - 1\right)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\left[\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{m}f\left(z\right)\right]\right]$$

Comment: Did you mean $z=\pi$ instead?

Comment: No, it is suppose to be $z=3$.

Comment: Then the only answer that you got is perfect.

Comment: Remember that the residue is the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term of the Laurent series. Such a coefficient can only be zero if the function is analytic.

Comment: @Kaynex Not only. The residue of $\;\frac1{z^2}\;$ at $\;z=0\;$ is zero, too...residues can be something pretty tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: the residue is zero as the function is analytic at $\;z=3\;$ and in some neighborhood of it.

If you insist in using limits then you need to do that with the function $\;z-3\;$ , as the $\;m\;$ you get there is zero...

Comment: I suppose @DonAntonio that with $m=0$ we can replace the derivative using Cauchy's Integral Formula and then use Cauchy's Thm to get the answer 0. ;-)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Perhaps that too, indeed. I just wanted to stress that the pole's order $\;m\;$ is zero in this case, so that formula yields something funny...or absurd, as you wish.

Comment: Of course I agree, the formula the OP gives only applies to "poles of order $m$". But it is interesting the all the $(-1)!$ cancel out when we use CIF, and that the absurd formula makes sense after all.